# Prove that all homomorphs of group $f: Z_{10} \longrightarrow Z_9$ it is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hello I have problems with exercise

For a positive integer $n> 1$ let us denote by $Z_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$

a) Prove that all homomorphs of group $f: Z_{10}  \longrightarrow Z_9$ it is trivial.
B) Find all homomorphisms of group $f: Z_{10}  \longrightarrow Z_8$

My atemp:

a) We have $f: Z_{10}  \longrightarrow Z_9$ is homomorphism and we have $f(x) =1$ but I don't know how to better justify.

b)How do I find all homomorphisms

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the isomorphism theorems?

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: For popular questions, please search before posting.